# Use Advance Custom Fields to fill text widget

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I have a custom WYSIWYG field setup in Advance Custom Fields Plugin and I want to show that content in a text widget on the sidebar / widgets.  I've tired the shortcode and the php code but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text widgets don't allow PHP code, [see the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Widgets). You can use a plugin ([see here](http://wordpress.org/plugins/php-code-widget/))

So putting `<?php echo get_field('name_of_your_field'); ?>` in the text area of your widget will not work, putting it in a page template should work. If you put it inside the loop you should use `<?php echo get_field('name_of_your_field'); ?>` and if you put it outside the loop you can get the field of a specific post ID by passing it through the get_fields function like this: `<?php echo get_field('name_of_your_field', 1234); ?>`.

Comment: <?php echo get_field('contentsidebar'); ?> is what I have in my text widget but still no luck.  The ACF only is set for one field and one field group.  The field is named "contentsidebar" without quotes.  Should there be a $ in there somewhere?  Thanks for the help!

Comment: The `$` is not the problem. Does it work when you put `<?php echo get_field('contentsidebar'); ?>` somewhere on a page (for instance in a template)? Because if so, then you know the code is not the problem.

Comment: It doesnt work when I put it a template file.  Does it need to be in the loop?  Does there have to be a post id declared? I see the data is being stored in the database fine.

Comment: Yes it needs to be in the loop (then you don't have to specify a post ID), but you can also test it outside the loop by adding a post ID like this: `<?php echo get_field('contentsidebar', 1234); ?>` where 1234 is the post ID.

Comment: That's it.  It doesn't work in the text widget but I can just put it in the page template and I'll be fine.  I'm sure text widget would work with the proper function to allow PHP in the widgets.

Comment: Hi, sorry forgot that text widgets don't allow php code. See my updated answer.